# Trying to use Pandas in Python - Error: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: python

I have installed the latest version of Pandas by using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

but I keep getting the following error message when i try to import into Python:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/_tseries.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Do I need to reinstall something? If so how do I do it? I have tried to find how to uninstall Pandas but I cant find it.

Comment: Did you try to install it from source or with pip or some other way also? Any files under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` are not installed by Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Pandas source code is written in Cython. The Cython pyx files are turned into .c files and compiled in .so libraries. The error you are seeing,

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/_tseries.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

says that `_tseries.so` was compiled as an ELF 32-bit binary, while your system (probably) needs an ELF 64-bit binary.

The proper way to fix this depends on how you've arrived at this situation. For example, if you have the full pandas source code in ~/src/pandas, then

```
cd ~/src/pandas/pandas
/bin/rm *.{c,cpp,so}   # <-- remove the 32-bit binaries
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/pandas/{build,dist}
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/bin/rm -rf pandas*    # <-- remove the egg file
cd ~/src/pandas
python setup.py build_ext --inplace && python setup.py install   # <-- will build 64-bit binaries on a 64-bit system.
```

will recompile the cython code and then attempt to install pandas.